# Top-down Merge Sort implementation in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement the top-down Merge Sort algorithm in C# as described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation). The following implementation is what I have come up with, however, it doesn't seem to sort the array correctly. I have gone through the debugger a few times but cannot figure out where the code goes wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;

class MergeSort
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] A = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
        int lastIndex = A.Length - 1;
        int[] B = new int[A.Length];
        Array.Copy(A, B, A.Length);
        MergeSortNumbers(B, 0, lastIndex, A);
        foreach (var item in A)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ", item);
        }
    }

    private static void MergeSortNumbers(int[] B, int iStart, int iEnd, int[] A)
    {
        int iMiddle = (iStart + iEnd) / 2;
        if ((iEnd - iStart) < 2)
        {
            // Merge(B, iStart, iMiddle, iEnd, A);
            return;
        }
        MergeSortNumbers(A, iStart, iMiddle - 1, B);
        MergeSortNumbers(A, iMiddle, iEnd, B);
        Merge(B, iStart, iMiddle, iEnd, A);
    }

    private static void Merge(int[] A, int iStart, int iMiddle, int iEnd, int[] B)
    {
        int i = iStart;
        int j = iMiddle;

        for (int k = iStart; k < iEnd; k++)
        {
            if (i < iMiddle && (j >= iEnd || A[i] <= A[j]))
            {
                B[k] = A[i];
                i = i + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                B[k] = A[j];
                j = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. you should know that `iEnd` is exclusive. that means `iEnd` it self does not take account in indexing. that's because of `j >= iEnd` condition in Merge method and `(iEnd - iStart) < 2` in MergeSortNumbers method.

`iMiddle` is also exclusive for left side. because of `i < iMiddle` condition in Merge method.

so basically don't decrement ends by 1. (you only decrement by one if ends were inclusive)

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] A = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    int[] B = new int[A.Length];
    Array.Copy(A, B, A.Length);
    MergeSortNumbers(B, 0, A.Length, A); // Do not decrement A.Length
    foreach (var item in A)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ", item);
    }
}

private static void MergeSortNumbers(int[] B, int iStart, int iEnd, int[] A)
{
    if ((iEnd - iStart) < 2) return;

    int iMiddle = (iStart + iEnd) / 2;
    MergeSortNumbers(A, iStart, iMiddle, B); // Do Not decrement iMiddle
    MergeSortNumbers(A, iMiddle, iEnd, B);
    Merge(B, iStart, iMiddle, iEnd, A);
}

private static void Merge(int[] A, int iStart, int iMiddle, int iEnd, int[] B)
{
    int i = iStart;
    int j = iMiddle;

    for (int k = iStart; k < iEnd; k++)
    {
        if (i < iMiddle && (j >= iEnd || A[i] <= A[j]))
        {
            B[k] = A[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            B[k] = A[j++];
        }
    }
}
```